# How to write our own application layer protocol (CoAP) above UDP?

Tags: networking, project, iot

I want to impliment Constrained application protocol(CoAP) above UDP. I want to use CoAP protocol instead of HTTP. From where I have to start study?

Comment: On what sort of device do you want to implement CoAP? There is almost certainly a library if you're using any relatively popular device which might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a couple of videos that could help you get started with CoAP:

1. [CoAP Tutorial - ARM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bSr5x5gKvA).
2. [CoAP in 5 minutes - IOTFriday](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4aaICV8ywA).

There are various open source libraries in several languages that you could use to build a program working upon CoAP, such as:

- [Python](https://github.com/Tanganelli/CoAPthon).
- [Java](https://github.com/automote/Califorium).
- [JavaScript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coap)
- [Ruby](https://github.com/nning/coap)
- [C](https://github.com/1248/microcoap)